# Inline style of tab panel header in PrimeNG tab view

Tags: css, angular, primeng

My app runs PrimeNG 1.1.2 and Angular 2.4.1. In my template I use a PrimeNG tab view with corresponding tab panels and respective headers. For a certain reason I want to style the appearance of the tab panel header.
For instance, say I want to set its font color to green:

```
<p-tabPanel header="Bezier Curve" [selected]="true" 
[headerStyle]="{'color': 'green'}">
```

However, this style does not apply and the font color doesn't change

Any pointers what I am missing?

**Edit**:
`font-color` replaced by `color`

Answer (score 2):

Try to override `ui-tabview-title` class and set required css in `style.css`

```
.ui-tabview-title{       
      color:green !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no CSS property with name `font-color`, you are looking for `color`:

```
<p-tabPanel header="Bezier Curve" [selected]="true" [headerStyle]="{'color': 'green'}">
```

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/) clearly states:

> Property `color` - Sets the color of text

Edit:

Problem is the following - after template rendering, header text is located between `a` tags which means you have to create CSS class that will change text color surrounded by `a` tags inside your header:

```
.greenText a {
    color: green;
}
```

And then use `headerStyleClass` attribute instead of `headerStyle` to apply CSS class:

```
<p-tabPanel header="Bezier Curve" [selected]="true" headerStyleClass="greenText">
```

Comment: Of course, you are right. However, it does not solve the problem. The style does not apply.

Comment: add ::ng-deep before make it worked

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, neither [headerStyle] nor [headerStyleClass] worked for me.
I switched to change the background-color, what -- for whatever reasons -- works.

```
<p-tabView>
<p-tabPanel [headerStyle]="db.isValid? { 'background-color':'#f58985' }: {}"
            [header]="db.name!"
            leftIcon="fa fa-tasks" *ngFor="let db of datasheets">...
```

Maybe that helps others too.
ps: i used PrimeNG 9.1.4 and Angular: 9.1.3

Answer (score 1):

We can use the custom header as well.

```
    <p-tabPanel [selected]="true">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <span style="color:green">Bezier Curve</span>
</ng-template>
</p-tabPanel>
```